# Does glm.nb (in R) give inflated p-values when tested under the null?

Tags: r, regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to do a simple test of glm.nb in R.

I simulate outcomes from a negative binomial using rnegbin.  I have a 0/1 case/control variable, and I'd like to test it for significance, but I'm finding that there are too many significant p values when I test null data:

```
pvalues = c()
for (blah in 1:20000) {
  outcomes = rnegbin(20,mu=30,theta=5)
  casecontrol =  c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10))
  model = glm.nb(outcomes~casecontrol,maxit=1000)
  pvalues = c(pvalues,summary(model)$coefficients[2,4])
}
hist(pvalues,40)
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?  I have negative binomial data and I'm testing it with negative binomial regression -- maybe there's something fundamental I'm not understanding?  Would be hugely appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual p-values based on maximum likelihood methods typically involve t statistics constructed by dividing the estimated parameters by the (Wald) standard errors, and then comparing the results to the standard normal distribution.  There are two sources of error here: The first is that, like the usual regression model, there is variability in the standard error that makes the t distribution more appropriate than the z distribution; and second error is that the distribution of the estimate is only approximately normal. Both of these problems lessen with larger sample sizes.  Here is some modified code that addresses both the t vs z and the sample sizes issues.

```
pvalues = c()
tvalues = c()
ndiv2 = 10
for (blah in 1:20000) {
outcomes = rnegbin(2*ndiv2,mu=30,theta=5)
casecontrol =  c(rep(0,ndiv2),rep(1,ndiv2))
model = glm.nb(outcomes~casecontrol,maxit=1000)
pvalues = c(pvalues,summary(model)$coefficients[2,4])
tvalues = c(tvalues,summary(model)$coefficients[2,3])
}
pvalues1 = 2*(1 - pt(abs(tvalues), 2*(ndiv2-1)))
hist(pvalues,40)
hist(pvalues1, 40)
mean(pvalues <=0.05)  # should be close to .05
mean(pvalues  <= 0.01)  # should be close to .01
mean(pvalues  <=0.005)  # should be close to .005
mean(pvalues <= 0.001)  # should be close to .001
mean(pvalues1 <=0.05)  # should be close to .05
mean(pvalues1  <= 0.01)  # should be close to .01
mean(pvalues1  <=0.005)  # should be close to .005
mean(pvalues1 <= 0.001)  # should be close to .001
```

Even with your small sample size of 20 (and to be clear, that is the issue with your results), the t-based results look a lot better.  And if you increase the sample size from 20 to 200 (by changing ndiv2 to 100), the results look even better.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  It works and seems totally reasonable!

Comment: Any reason why they report z and not t?  Seems like a strange choice.

Comment: The problem with "t" is that it really doesn't have a t distribution under any circumstance, unlike the usual regression model where it has exactly the t distribution under the classical assumptions. There really isn't any guarantee that the t distribution will work better here, but in many cases (like here) it seems to be quite an improvement.

Comment: Instead of Wald's you could use LR test. It is almost always recommended over Wald test as it is known to converge to its asymptotic distribution with smaller n.

Comment: Hmmm ... that has not been my experience in simulations I have done and seen. I have seen examples involving binary data where LR provides results even worse than shown by the OP in terms of too small p-values. Also, the LR test is not directional.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, the test will generate the uniform p.value only if you estimate theta correctly or that you provide theta.

You have a small sample size, making the estimate of dispersion parameter (theta) less stable and inaccurate.

You can write something that allows you to trace back what gives the small p-values:

```
library(MASS)
res = lapply(1:20000,function(i){
  set.seed(i)
  outcomes = rnegbin(20,mu=30,theta=5)
  casecontrol =  c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10))
  model = glm.nb(outcomes~casecontrol,maxit=1000)
  data.frame(
  seed=i,
  p= summary(model)$coefficients[2,4],
  converged = model$converged,
  theta = model$theta
  )
})

res = do.call(rbind,res)

head(res)
  seed         p converged     theta
1    1 0.5062888      TRUE  7.361704
2    2 0.5727485      TRUE  4.116351
3    3 0.6651575      TRUE 10.457000
4    4 0.9183633      TRUE  7.348471
5    5 0.1878434      TRUE  8.519955
6    6 0.3917041      TRUE  3.897681

hist(res$p,br=40)
```

[image]

It's more than 0.05 and 1.5 times more than expected:

```
mean(res$p<0.05)
[1] 0.0815
```

We can look at the significant ones:

```
head(res[order(res$p),],10)
       seed            p converged     theta
10794 10794 8.936969e-09      TRUE 15.504781
18191 18191 3.835794e-07      TRUE 12.724549
8409   8409 6.447190e-07      TRUE 33.455136
6371   6371 6.618804e-07      TRUE 93.952097
496     496 7.851968e-07      TRUE 13.578130
5600   5600 1.606424e-06      TRUE  9.295402
8531   8531 3.123901e-06      TRUE  8.908264
9109   9109 3.126698e-06      TRUE 24.742166
1470   1470 4.151136e-06      TRUE 18.737336
17462 17462 4.298971e-06      TRUE 16.478784
```

You can see the theta estimates are much higher, indicating the model is estimating a lower dispersion (dispersion = 1/theta). We can look at how the simulation is:

```
set.seed(10794)
outcomes = rnegbin(20,mu=30,theta=5)
grp = c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10))
boxplot(outcomes ~ grp ,horizontal = TRUE)
rug(outcomes[grp==0],col="blue")
rug(outcomes[grp==1],col="red")
```

[image]

Which seems pretty decent if the model doesn't know what to expect for theta.

Let's provide theta as you simulated and perform the test:

```
sim_p = sapply(1:20000,function(i){
  set.seed(i)
  outcomes = rnegbin(20,mu=30,theta=5)
  casecontrol =  c(rep(0,10),rep(1,10))
  model = glm(outcomes~casecontrol,maxit=1000,family=neg.bin(5))
  summary(model)$coefficients[2,4]
})

hist(sim_p,br=40)

mean(sim_p<0.05)
[1] 0.05425
```

[image]

If you are going to use this glm for testing, give a second thought to whether you have enough samples to estimate theta correctly.